# vHosting on Apache2.2 won't work properly

Tags: apache, apache2, virtualhost

So, I set up two virtual hosts on my apache and now, I can't access the server via localhost anymore.
Here's my vhosts.conf:

```
NameVirtualHost *:80

<VirtualHost *:80>
    ServerAdmin webmaster@serv.net.local
    DocumentRoot "W:/www"
    <Directory "W:/www/">
        AllowOverride All
        Order Allow,Deny
        Allow from all
    </Directory>
    ServerName serv.net.local
    ErrorLog "logs/serv.net.local-error.log"
    CustomLog "logs/serv.net.local-access.log" common
</VirtualHost>

<VirtualHost *:80>
    ServerAdmin webmaster@symfony.net.local
    DocumentRoot "W:/www/symfony/web"
    <Directory "W:/www/symfony/web/">
        AllowOverride All
        Order Allow,Deny
        Allow from all
    </Directory>
    ServerName symdev.net.local
    ServerAlias symfony.net.local
    ErrorLog "logs/symdev.net.local-error.log"
    CustomLog "logs/symdev.net.local-access.log" common
</VirtualHost>
```

All domains are in my hosts-file and are properly resolved. But I can only access the second vHost and get a connection reset error when trying to access localhost or serv.net.local. Same for using 127.0.0.1...

Any ideas whats wrong with this config?

Comment: Check logs, possibly turn on debug level, check contents of Listen and Port directives, or if there isn't NameVirtualHost elsewhere across the config. There are also commands like apache2ctl -t -D DUMP_VHOSTS to get list of existing virtualhosts and default vhost. Must be something trivial. Also check access to specified DocumentRoot(s). Possibly but unlikely that some other enabled virtualhosting module causes malfunction in vhosts. Question perhaps should be moved to superuser.com . Part of your config you pasted looks ok.

Comment: DUMP_VHOSTS lists serv.net.local as well as symdev.net.local in it's list and also only the one file. Everything seems to be fine.

Comment: if you have "connection reset" there must be something in logs, assuming you check pure virtual host, e.g. html or text file under vhost DocumetRoot, no CGI/FCGI etc. Maybe you disabled DirectoryIndex and put no index.html file?

Comment: Thank you, the DirectoryIndex did the trick. Haven't thought about that.

Comment: to avoid further caveats, it is useful to put "hello, this is here.i.am.domain.com" >> index.html in empty directory, so you were always 100% sure where you are.

Answer (score 0):

According to discussion in comments, VirtualHost DocumentRoot was not readable because it contained no index, and directory listing was disabled, so fixing it solved the issue.